# Stop node server from another file

Tags: node.js

I have the following two files.

file1.js and file2.js

From file1.js, I start a node server that exists in files2.js by using Node `exec` from child process.

What I would like to do is, start the server that exists file2.js from file1.js by calling `exec` or `spawn` method from `child_process`. Stop it after 10s or so and restart the server again. How could I achieve this?

What I've tried is that, after I started the server, I called `process.exit()` and then tried to execute the `exec` function again, but since the process has exited, the second call to `exec` never actually reached.

I want to achieve this without using any external package though.

Comment: Why don't you try it the other way around? Eg.: starting a main process and create/handle a server(s) in `child_process`

Comment: @lependu I am so dumb :)

Comment: No worries. I think we all were there :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is ***setTimeout()***:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
let stopped = false;
exec('command to start the server in file two', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // do stuff
  }
});
setTimeout(function(){ 
     exec('stop the server in file two', (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
        stopped = true;
        if(err){
          // handle error
        } else {
          // do stuff
        }
     })
}, 10000);

if(stopped) {
   exec('start server again', (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
       stopped = false;
       if(err){
        // handle error
      } else {
        // do stuff
      }
   })
}
```